# Rails db:migrate / db:create. Existed databases conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I previously was making some webapps using Spring MVC + PostgreSQL on my PC.

Wanted to try RoR, faced strange prob with DB connection, google isn't helping.

I created i new Rails web-application, made one model and tried to make a migration. (Last Rails gem, 5.0.0.beta3)

**The problem is:**

When i'm running db:migrate/create/drop
Rails is trying to manipulate my existing DB's instead of creation new ones.

-i have a few PostgreSQL databases on my local PostgreSQL server, which i still want to keep active on it. Lets say 'XXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYY', 'ZZZZZZZZZ'

Once i run db:create i get the following log:

```
C:\Users\****\RubymineProjects\sample_articles>rails db:create
'XXXXXXX' already exists
```

DB migrate is executed successfully and also creating one additional database 'sample_articles_development', which is the name as i specify in my `database.yml`. BUT the new tables appears to my existed database 'XXXXXXX'(which i didn't configure in any configs).

This is my `database.yml` config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_articles_development
  username: rails
  password: *******
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_articles_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_articles_production
  username: sample_articles
  password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_ARTICLES_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Only `rake db:create` will try to create a new database.  `rake db:migrate` will use an existing one (which it reads from database.yml).  You refer to calling `rake db:create` as "doing a migration".  it isn't - you're just confusing things.

Comment: Ok. Maybe confusing. I'm completely new to Rails. Ok, lets say the problem is in db:migrate.

But still the prob is that i can't understand why does it use one of my existing DB's

Comment: Well then your question becomes "When i'm running db:migrate Rails is trying to manipulate my existing DB's", and this is the expected behaviour, so there's nothing wrong.

Comment: why is this expected behavior? i do set a DB name in my `database.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a `$DATABASE_URL` variable in your environment. That will override the value in database.yml.

```
unset DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thank you, didn't thought about this case.